# concat two json objects from different api by id in axios get and store

Tags: reactjs, axios, mobx, mobx-react

I have a question about how to add the second nested api query in axios. The second api query to get the json object based on the id from the first api array json. And then concat to global array in function Retrieve()?

**first api url:**

```
'/api/sets'
```

**second api children:**

```
'/api/sets/' + todo.id + '/tasks'
```

**responce global json from first api url:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "list1",
        "description": "description1"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "list2",
        "description": "description2"
    }
]
```

**responce second json children from api by id first api:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "task1",
        "description": "description task1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "task2",
        "description": "description task2"
    }
]
```

**and finally expected combined stored array json**

```
[
     {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "list1",
        "description": "description1",
        "task": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "task1",
                "description": "description task1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "task2",
                "description": "description task2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "list2",
        "description": "description2",
        "task": [{
                "id": 10,
                "name": "task1",
                "description": "description task1"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "task2",
                "description": "description task2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

code js:
index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import TodoStore from './store';

const Root = (
    <Provider TodoStore={TodoStore}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(Root, document.getElementById('root'));
```

store.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { observable, action, configure, runInAction } from 'mobx';
import axios from 'axios';
configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' });

class TodoStore {
    @observable todos = [];

    @action Retrieve = () => {
        axios
            .get('/api/sets')
            .then(response => {
                let tempTodos = response.data;
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.todos = tempTodos;
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
}

const store = new TodoStore();
export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you API does not support GraphQL endpoint, then you should have to expand your Retrive() action and do extra XHR request for sets id to combine results from API endpoint 1 and 2.

```
 @action Retrieve = () => {
        axios
            .get('/api/sets')
            .then(response => {
                let tempTodos = response.data;

                let todosWithTasks = tempTodos.map(todo => {

                   let tasks = null;

                    axios.get('/api/sets/' + todo.id + '/tasks')
                      .then(response2 => {
                          tasks = response2.data;
                      }).catch(error => {
                          console.log(error);
                      });

                    todo.task = tasks;
                    return todo;

                });

                // `todosWithTasks` is joined API1 and API2

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works, all api is joined, now I have another little problem. If set `@observable.ref todos = [];` or `@observable.shallow todos = [];` in console log key `task` exitst with array of objects, but when I set `@observable todos = [];` key `task` no exist.

`console.log`

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:
    description: "false"
    id: 121
    name: "list1"
    task: Array(2)
      0: {id: 10, name: "task1", description: "description task1", state: false, position: 1}
      1: {id: 11, name: "task2", description: "description task2", state: true position: 2}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
  1:
    description: "false"
    id: 9
    name: "list2"
    task: Array(2)
      0: {id: 3, name: "task1", description: "description task1", state: false, position: 3}
      1: {id: 7, name: "task2", description: "description task2", state: false, position: 5}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

and if try map key `task`

```
index.module.js:206 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at eval (TodoItem.jsx:17)
    at eval (index.module.js:220)
    at eval (index.module.js:198)
    at trackDerivedFunction (mobx.module.js:1212)
    at Reaction.track (mobx.module.js:1752)
    at useObserver (index.module.js:196)
    at wrappedComponent (index.module.js:220)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:12938)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:14627)
    at updateSimpleMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:14573)

react-dom.development.js:17117 The above error occurred in the <wrappedComponent> component:
    in wrappedComponent (created by n)
    in n (created by inject-with-TodoStore(Object))
    in inject-with-TodoStore(Object) (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by n)
    in n (created by inject-with-TodoStore(App))
    in inject-with-TodoStore(App)
    in e
```

`code index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import TodoStore from './TodoStore';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const Root = (
    <Provider TodoStore={TodoStore}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(Root, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

`TodoStore.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {observable, action, computed, configure, runInAction} from 'mobx';
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'api';
configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' });

class TodoStore {
    @observable.shallow todos = [];

    @action Retrieve = () => {
        axios
            .get('/sets')
            .then(response => {
                let tempTodos = response.data;

                let todosWithTasks = tempTodos.map(todo => {
                    let tasks = null;

                    axios
                        .get('/sets/' + todo.id + '/tasks')
                        .then(response2 => {
                            todo.task = response2.data;
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    return todo;
                });
                runInAction(() => {
                    this.todos = todosWithTasks;
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
}

const store = new TodoStore();
export default store;
```

`app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import { toJS } from 'mobx';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('TodoStore')
@observer
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const TodoStore = this.props.TodoStore;
        console.log(toJS(TodoStore.todos));

        return (
            <div className="App">
                {TodoStore.todos.map(todo => (
                    <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.props.TodoStore.Retrieve();
    }
}
TodoItem.wrappedComponent.propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    TodoStore: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default App;
```

`todoitem`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import TodoItemTask from './TodoItemtask';

const TodoItem = inject('TodoStore')(
    observer(props => {
        const TodoStore = props.TodoStore;

        return (
            <>
                <div key={props.todo.id} className="todo-item">
                    <span>{props.todo.id}</span>
                    <h5>{props.todo.name}</h5>
                    <p>{props.todo.description}</p>

                    {props.todo.task.map((item, index) => (
                        <TodoItemTask key={index + item.id} item={item} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </>
        );
    })
);

TodoItem.wrappedComponent.propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    TodoStore: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default TodoItem;
```

`TodoItemTask.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

const TodoItemTask = inject('TodoStore')(
    observer(props => {
        const TodoStore = props.TodoStore;

        return (
            <>
                <div key={props.item.id} className="todo-item">
                    <span>{props.index}</span>
                    <p>{props.item.name}</p>
                    <p>{props.item.description}</p>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    })
);

TodoItemTask.wrappedComponent.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    TodoStore: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default TodoItemTask;
```

no errors and render all data if set static data

```
@observable todos = [
     {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "list1",
        "description": "description1",
        "task": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "task1",
                "description": "description task1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "task2",
                "description": "description task2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "list2",
        "description": "description2",
        "task": [{
                "id": 10,
                "name": "task1",
                "description": "description task1"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "task2",
                "description": "description task2"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: You have to check if tasks are loaded from API looks like you are trying to map on undefined item.

Comment: first obejcts of `todos > id, name, description` is render ok , only not map obejcts by key `task`

Comment: You can check if tasks are available by doing `{props.todo.task && props.todo.task.map(...)}`

Comment: looks like key `task` no exist, flag isLoading checked if all api loaded, in console.log key exist if set `@observable.ref todos = [];` or `@observable.shallow todos = [];`

Comment: question why mobx not observable nested keys with array objects. In console.log key exist only if obesrvable with options `@observable.ref todos = []; or @observable.shallow todos = []`

Comment: i would be glad to help, but i don't have experience with mobx state management solution. You can try to open new question and specify your problem and also tag it mobx reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a problem with mobx, I found that two api url json are incorrectly connected in this function.
In `console.log(todosWithTasks)`  it looks right, but this `console.log (JSON.stringify(todosWithTasks))` not.

this is actual code

```
import React from 'react';
import {observable, action, computed, configure, runInAction} from 'mobx';
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'api';
configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' });

class TodoStore {
    @observable todos = [];

@action async Retrieve = () => {
    this.isLoading = true;
    await axios
        .get('/sets')
        .then(async response => {
            let tempTodos = response.data;
            tempTodos.forEach(todo => (todo.task = []));
            let todosWithTasks = tempTodos.map(todo => {
                axios
                    .get('/sets/' + todo.id + '/tasks')
                    .then(response2 => {
                        todo.task = response2.data;
                        return todo;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                return todo;
            });
            runInAction(() => {
                console.log(todosWithTasks);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(todosWithTasks));
                this.todos = todosWithTasks;
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
   };

}

const store = new TodoStore();
export default store;
```

**output from console.log(JSON.stringify(todosWithTasks))**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"list1","description":"description1","task":[]}]
```

output from console.log(todosWithTasks) looks fine

```
(1) [{…}]
    0:
        description: "description1"
        id: 1
        name: "list1"
        task: Array(1)
            0: {id: 1, name: "task1", description: "description task1"}
            length: 1
            __proto__: Array(0)
        __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

therefore, it does not render in the map function, because the `key task` is empty.

If the modified merged json file localy, in axios it's everything ok. In console.log (JSON.stringify (todosWithTasks)) everything fine.

```
    @action Retrieve() {
        axios
            .get('localhost:3000/src/data.json')
            .then(response => {
                let tempTodos = response.data;
                tempTodos.forEach(todo => (todo.editing = false));

                runInAction(() => {
                    this.todos = tempTodos;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(tempTodos));
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```